# If statement not working after update query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a mail system, which have been great so far. However I'm stuck on the "delete mail" part.

In my database i have 2 columns (recdel and senddel) which responds to true or false.
Whenever a user press "delete" it updates the column to true based on sender or recipent and hides it from correct persons inbox. 
When both the recipent and the sender have pressed delete i want to remove it from the database, unnecessary to have it there in case both parties have deleted it.

The issue stands when both parties have pressed delete, one of the parties must press delete once again for it to be deleted from the database (removed the hiding part for testing purposes).

The problem seems to be with the if statements, it wont go on to the third if statement after update query untill both colums are true, then it moves to the third if statement when delete is pressed for the third time.

I've also tried putting the third if statement inside the 2 first if statements, still having the same problem though.

Any thoughts?

```
if(person == sender) {
    $query = 'UPDATE `email` SET `senddel`="true" WHERE `id`='.$id.'';
}

if(person == recipent) {
    $query = 'UPDATE `email` SET `recdel`="true" WHERE `id`='.$id.'';
}

if(recdel == 'true' && senddel == 'true'){
    delfromdb
}
```

Comment: What is your actual code? `recdel` is defined as the return of the query? Do you check that status of the query?

Comment: `person == sender`? Those aren't variables. they're undefined constants, which php will politely auto-variabalize, and since they're also undefined variables, most likely you're just doing `null == null`.

Comment: One approach would be to attempt the delete action whenever an update is made to either the `recdel` or `senddel` columns. For example, `DELETE from \`email\` WHERE \`recdel\` AND \`senddel\` AND \`id\` = ? `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning to columns in the database doesn't automatically update PHP variables. You need to do another SQL query:

```
$query = 'DELETE FROM email WHERE recdel = "true" and senddel = "true" AND id = $id';
```

Comment: delfromdb is a function which deletes items from the db based on id's, so there is already a query for it. I'll update my question with proper coding.

Comment: How are you setting `$recdel` and `$senddel`?

Comment: And assigning values to PHP variables doesn't execute a SQL statement against the database, no matter how much that value looks like the text of a SQL statement. The code is just setting a PHP variable to a string value.

Comment: @spencer7593 I took it as pseudo-code, like all the missing `$`.

Comment: @Barmar Above the if statements i collect information from the DB based on the e-mail id. Then I update the db based on the id of the conversation in the first two if statements. Then i thought the third if statement would read off the update, but it seems i would need to connect once again to the database in the third if statement to check if the two columns are set?

Comment: That's correct. Nothing automatically updates PHP variables from the database.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

These actions aren't occurring at the same time. Hence you wouldn't trigger the statement to be true.

I think your scenario would only work if the sender sent an email to himself.

You need more conditions in your "if" statements checking the status of the recdel/senddel independent of the person being a sender or receiver.